# Javascript date Variable

Tags: javascript

```
var dt1=new Date("2013/05/25"); //yyyy/MM/dd
var dt2=new Date("2013/05/24");

if(dt1>dt2)
{
    alert("invalid Date!");  
}
```

This code is working in all Browsers..

But if we select:

```
var dt1=new Date("25/05/2013"); //dd/MM/yyyy
var dt2=new Date("24/05/2013");

if(dt1>dt2)
{
    alert("invalid Date!");  
}
```

This code is not working in all the browsers? Why?
Is there any specifc date format that should be accepted by all the browsers? Is there any standard for DateTime as well? Thank you........

Comment: What does 'working' and 'not working' mean, in context?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: This is because javascript Date only supports input in valid ISO compliant date format which is yyyy/mm/dd.

Comment: It's not possible that it's parser will recognize any format of date. How could the parser know if a two digit number is a day, month or year?

Comment: not working means that we are not getting the required output, if dt1>dt2, it should display the alert message, but it is not displaying..

Comment: You can see the standard here. http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a standard for [Javascript Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

One of the contructors is `new Date(dateString);` and for dateString there is an explanation:

> String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the parse method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps).

And in IE is a little different [IE WAY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cd9w2te4%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

So the most secure way to do what you want is either use the last constructor:

`new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond]);`

or your dateString must be `yyyy/mm/dd`

Comment: Which means that if you need to accept user-entered dates you need to parse the string they enter yourself according to whatever rules you want to specify and then use the `new Date(year, month, day)` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes **dd/MM/yyyy format will not support** for all the browsers and we cont change this type of date format into string also,even in php also we cont use this formate via strtotime() function

Comment: Why would you approve [this suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2232828)? What good does indenting code by a further 4 spaces achieve?